# Laravel $data получает пустой массив при dd() в Сервисе метод update как можно исправить чтобы работал метод обновления

Tags: php, laravel, update

```
    public function updateDish(array $data, string $dish )
{
    dd($data);
    $dish = Dish::findOrFail($dish);
   
    if (isset($data['image'])) {
        // Обработка изображения и сохранение пути
        $imagePath = $data['image']->store('public/dishes');
        $data['image'] = Storage::url($imagePath);
    }

    $dish->update($data);

    return $dish;
```

Дал пустой массив без данных
[] // app/Services/DishService.php:39

Вот моя валидация , если уберу sometimes будет ругаться required на поля

```
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'name' => 'sometimes|required|max:255',
        'deskriptions' => 'sometimes|required',
        'image' => 'sometimes|image|max:900',
        'price' => 'sometimes|required|numeric',
    ];
}
```

}

Метод для обновления в контроллере

```
 public function updateDish(UpdateDishRequest $request , $id)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validated();
    $dish = $this->dishService->updateDish($validatedData, $id);
    return response()->json($dish, 200);
}
```

Comment: А данные то Вы передаёте? Somtimes означает "проверять, если поле передано" -- вы ничего не передали в body, пустой массив и получили.